# Get ID from name with Access DLookUp function

Tags: sql, ms-access

Long story short I need to DLookUp an ID based on the name of a record. In this case I need to get the ID of a city based on it's name. When I try

```
DLookUp("ID","Cities","Name = London")
```

it says it cant find name "London"

Side Question:
Can I write queries in Access using pure SQL somehow?

Big thanks for help

Comment: Need to add single quotes to London, e.g. `DLookUp("ID","Cities","Name = 'London'")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by John Wu, you have to put single quotes around `London` to indicate that this is not another field in the database but rather a string literal:

```
DLookUp("ID", "Cities", "Name = 'London'")
```

Where this is a simple way in VBA to retrieve a single value, you can always use fully fledged SQL to retrieve entire records (multiple values of a database entry) or a recordset (consisting of multiple records). That would look something like this:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID FROM Cities WHERE Name = 'London'")
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Debug.Print rst("ID")
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```